# Context Switch without interrupt disabled?

Tags: arm, stm32, interrupts, stm32f4

I developing a program on ARM M4 where I don't actually want to disable interrupt even when doing a context switch. If any interrupt occurs during context switch, is it possible to handle it soon after the context switch? Can I use the Interrupt set and clear pending registers (NVIC_ISPR and NVIC_ICPR)" for this purpose? If not, what is the solution?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do. What does a context switch mean to you? Can you just disable/enable interrupts? Would `cpsid`/`cpsie` work then?

Comment: when you do figure out what you are asking this is better suited for stack overflow.

Comment: Normally interrupt is disabled using cpsid before doing a context switch. If there is a interrupt between context switch it will be ignored. Keep interrupt enabled during context switch can make the OS unstable. Is there anyway to handle the interrupt that occurred during context switch after the context switch?